# Нужна ли запятая после "конце"?

Tags: пунктуация

*Разве только в самом конце минуты две, не более.*

Comment: Что-то да нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Разве только в самом конце – минуты две, не более.***

Предложение неполное.

Обособляется **присоединительный** оборот с количественным  значением.

Другой вариант: ***Разве только в самом конце, и минуты две, не более***.

И – присоединительный союз.